# Make clang-format not remove spaces between variable type and variable name when defining variables

Tags: clang-format

Is it possible to make clang-format not to remove spaces between the variable type and the variable name? (without using //clan-format off). I have this code

```
   double   coordinate;
   int      pickId;
   int      hideInSecs;
   bool     isTriangulation
```

and after applying clang format it gets converted to this, which is not as good as before

```
   double coordinate;
   int pickId;
   int hideInSecs;
   bool isTriangulation
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
AlignConsecutiveMacros:       AcrossComments
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: AcrossComments
```